# Drop Down List Show Getdate() +2 years and - 2 years

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have searched the internet but haven't found an answer, not sure if this is a stupid question, but here goes

I want to create a drop down list which automatically adds years to the list, without me adding them. There are 2 optioins to configure the datasource and create a query OR code it in C#

I was just wondering if it is possible to show the current year + 2 years and - 2 years, purely using getdate(). For example, I want 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016 to show,

The code below will only show 2012, but I want the other years to also show

```
select Year(dateadd(year, -2, getdate()))
```

Im not sure if I am going the right way about this, but I would like the drop down list to show the years automatically.

Let me know if you require further information, I am not so great at c#, and if you are going to down rate my question at least let me know why....

Comment: c# is a better option.

Comment: Wow I have -3 on the question already

Comment: You'd need to UNION all the items together, the best option is to use .NET and loop from -2 to 2, adding the loop value as a number of years to the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, you want to bind value from C# code which is a lot faster than querying SQL Server.

For example,

```
int start = DateTime.Now.Year - 2;
int end = start + 5;
for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this has worked like a charm! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tally table for this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 --five years
IDENTITY(INT,-2,1) AS N
INTO #tally
FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns

SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,N,GETDATE()))
FROM #tally

DROP TABLE #tally
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, this definetly shows the years, but I was just unable to show them in the dropdown list